# Stop form submission when an html button with onserverclick enabled is clicked in an asp.net web App

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, submit-button

I have a button in an asp.net application which submits a form.

```
    <input type="submit" id="sumbit" value="Sign up" runat="server" 
     onserverclick="sumbit_ServerClick2" class="submitbutton"/>
```

I have a javascript function which returns true and false. How do i prevent the form from being submitted if the javascript function returns false.
I cant access the form tag as i am using masterpage and the whole contentplacedholder is enclosed within a runat="server" form.

Comment: Is the javascript doing some type of validation?  if so look into the validation controls to prevent postback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your function is called `yourJsFunction`, I think you can just use `onclick="return !!yourJsFunction();"` on the input element, like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="sumbit" value="Sign up" runat="server" onclick="return !!yourJsFunction();"
 onserverclick="sumbit_ServerClick2" class="submitbutton"/>
```

Use `!!` in front of the function call to force a boolean value.

--

For ASP.NET Button use `onClientClick="return !!yourJsFunction();"`.

[**Read more here**](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_button_onclientclick.asp).

Comment: its an html button. onclientclick is not a valid attribute.

Comment: Thanks @thunderbird, saw that now. Updated the answer :)

Comment: i have already tried that but it didnt work but what @NETRICITY suggested worked `onclick="if (!yourFunction()) return false;"`

Comment: Wierd, have you tried `return !!yourFunction()` - which just forces a boolean value.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `onclick` attribute to test the return value of your JS function:

```
<input type="submit" id="sumbit" value="Sign up" runat="server" 
     onserverclick="sumbit_ServerClick2" class="submitbutton" 
     onclick="if (!yourFunction()) return false;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the button type to "button" (defaults to submit), this will disable the submit of the form and rely upon the __doPostBack() to handle the wiring up.

```
<button id="MyButton" runat="server" type="button" onserverclick="MyButton_Click">Submit</button>
```